# php form not inserting data into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got this php/html form where the user can assign a job to a driver and when submitted: it would be added to the database.

this form was working up until I added the driver id field (this is based on the driver selected beforehand)

I also binded the url to represent the selected driver via ID: http://localhost/finalyear/add-job.php?driver_id=13

code before submit button is clicked:

```
if (!isset($_GET['driver_id']))
{
echo "You shouldn't have got to this page";
exit;
}

$drive = $_GET['driver_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM driver WHERE driver.driver_id = :driver"; 
$term = $conn->prepare($query);
$term->bindValue(':driver', $drive);
$term->execute();
```

$drive = $term->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

html:

```
<select class="form-control" name="ID" > 
        <option value="<? echo $term['driver_id'];?>"><?php echo $drive->driver_id; ?></option>

        </select>
```

code after button is clicked:

```
try{
       $conn = new PDO(DB_DATA_SOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

}
catch (PDOException $exception) 
{
echo "Oh no, there was a problem" . $exception->getMessage();
}


//get the form data
$newDriver = $_POST['ID'];

$conn=getConn();
$successJob=insertJob($conn,$newDriver);
if ($successJob) {
$error = "The job has now been added to the site!";
include("add-job.php");
}
else {
    $error = "This failed";
}

function insertJob($conn,$newDriver)
 {
 $query="INSERT INTO jobs VALUES (NULL, :driver_id)";

$stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':driver_id', $newDriver);
$affected_rows = $stmt->execute();

    if($affected_rows==1){
        return true;
    }else{

        return false;
    }

 }







$conn=NULL; //close the connection

}
```

so now with adding the driver_id, the page is blank, doesnt give any sort of error and im unsure of why this is happening. done various tests etc.

this was all fine until i introduced that option control to hold the driver's id.
also want to note that it may also be caused by the url  bind, because when you click the submit button, it takes me to a black page saying "I shouldnt have got there" and the url removes the driver_id bind i did.

Comment: what is the type... of the value?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO jobs (field1) VALUES (NULL, :driver_id)";`

Comment: an integer, in the database ive listed it as "INT"

Comment: Do try and specify the columns you're inserting into. Don't just blind insert and *hope* that the columns match your expectations. This indentation is also a complete wreck. Keep your code organized and orderly so bugs can't hide in the mess. This is especially important when asking others to review your code.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: im not using a framework, and ive already specified where its going into the database: into the driver_id column